# How to use external file to modify a variable when the app is in production?

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, vue.js

I have a web page made with .Net Core 2.1 and Vue, when the web application is in production mode, how to leave a config file as the Net Core appsettings.json and modify a variable.
My doubt is also about how to build the content of it, and how to access to that variable in one of my component page in vue.

Thank you

Comment: I've had the same problem recently and I solved it by putting my `appconfig.json` file in `dist` folder (production build folder), which I fetch via axios in `main.js` after imports. Once you change something in `appconfig.json` you don't have to rebuild the app, the changes are visible after you refresh page.

Comment: @dziraf I solved it by adding a js file in the folder wwwroot / js since it is the folder that when publishing the project, it is still there, I put my variables and I accessed them with an import {variable} from '...' thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you may be after is External Configuration Store pattern
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store
This will allow you to store the configuration information in external storage, and provide an interface that can be used to quickly and efficiently read and update configuration settings

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say that the external file is for vue, thath is, javascript